# How to make A Weather command? (Discord.py)

Tags: command, discord.py, weather

So I made this weather command down below, but for some reason, it only says the bot is typing, and there gives a error. This is the code:

```
import requests

@client.command()
async def weather(ctx, *, city: str):
    city_name = city
    complete_url = base_url + "appid=" + api_key + "&q=" + city_name
    response = requests.get(complete_url)
    x = response.json()
    channel = ctx.message.channel
    if x["cod"] != "404":
        async with channel.typing():
            y = x["main"]
            current_temperature = y["temp"]
            current_temperature_celsiuis = str(round(current_temperature - 273.15))
            current_pressure = y["pressure"]
            current_humidity = y["humidity"]
            z = x["weather"]
            weather_description = z[0]["description"]
            weather_description = z[0]["description"]
            embed = discord.Embed(title=f"Weather in {city_name}",
                              color=ctx.guild.me.top_role.color,
                              timestamp=ctx.message.created_at,)
            embed.add_field(name="Descripition", value=f"**{weather_description}**", inline=False)
            embed.add_field(name="Temperature(C)", value=f"**{current_temperature_celsiuis}°C**", inline=False)
            embed.add_field(name="Humidity(%)", value=f"**{current_humidity}%**", inline=False)
            embed.add_field(name="Atmospheric Pressure(hPa)", value=f"**{current_pressure}hPa**", inline=False)
            embed.set_thumbnail(url="https://i.ibb.co/CMrsxdX/weather.png")
            embed.set_footer(text=f"Requested by {ctx.author.name}")
        await channel.send(embed=embed)
    else:
        await channel.send("City not found.")
```

But the error I get from this is saying 'main' is a keyerror

Comment: Can you please give us a full traceback?

Comment: So Im using Openweather to make this, and whenever I run this code to help use their API for weather, it gives me some sort of error. Can you please explain a alternative way to make a weather command with discord.py?

Comment: I mean exactly this error what you mean in the comment and a full traceback of this error